# Ubuntu 16.04 Access Memory Contents through /proc

Tags: 16.04, firefox, cache

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 12.04. In 12.04 we could access memory contents through file descriptors. Like if we want to access cached Firefox video, we could get its process id and then check the file listing in /proc/FF process id/fd. And from there we could simply copy the entire cached content / video.

That process has apparently changed in 16.04. May be it has got to do with Systemd. How can we copy FF cached vids in 16.04 like we could do in 12.04 ?